# Return calculated object

Tags: objective-c, methods

I have a basic Rectangle class. I am trying to calculate the upper right corner given the origin, width, and height.

I set the origin, width, and height in my main.m and I can NSLog them and get the right values.When I try to call a Rectangle method called upperRight on the rectangle I get 0, 0 regardless of the inputs.

Here's the line I'm using in main.m:

```
NSLog(@"The upper right corner is at x=%f and y=%f", myRectangle.upperRight.x, myRectangle.upperRight.y);
```

Here's the relevant (I think) of the Rectangle class:

```
@implementation Rectangle

{
XYPoint *origin;
XYPoint *originCopy;
XYPoint *upperRight;
}

@synthesize width, height;

-(XYPoint *) upperRight {
upperRight.x = origin.x + width;
upperRight.y = origin.y + height;
return upperRight;
}
```

Even if I try to set upperRight.x = 200 in the method I still get 0,0 returned in main.

I'm obviously missing some basic understanding here.

EDIT:

Here's what is in main to set the values:

```
    Rectangle *myRectangle = [[Rectangle alloc]init];
    XYPoint *myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
    XYPoint *testPoint = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
    //XYPoint *translateAmount = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

    [myRectangle setWidth: 15 andHeight: 10.0];
    [myPoint setX: 4 andY: 3];
```

Here's XYPoint.m:

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint

@synthesize x, y;

-(void) setX:(float)xVal andY:(float)yVal {
x = xVal;
y = yVal;
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you show when you do the settings/calls?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `XYPoint` is the same as `CG/NSPoint` (a `struct` with two `float`s), then why are you holding pointers to them?

I think you mean:

```
implementation Rectangle
{
    XYPoint origin;
    XYPoint originCopy;
    XYPoint upperRight;
}

// Strange semantics here... a method that modifies upperRight before returning it?!?
// So why is upperRight an instance variable?  Something is rotten in the state of Denmark.
-(XYPoint) upperRight {
    upperRight.x = origin.x + width;
    upperRight.y = origin.y + height;
    return upperRight;
}
```

This is only guesswork as you don't disclose `XYPoint`...

Comment: I'm a beginner. What is the right way to return that upper corner?

Comment: @tangobango You need to keep origin and size (see NS/CGRect).  You then calculate upper right from origin + size so there is no need to keep upper right as an instance variable.

Comment: So I should be making this calculation in main?

Comment: @tangobango If by "making it" you mean "calculating it", then yes.  You need to consider what instance variables need to exist in order for your class to work and what can be calculated.  However the point of my answer was that you are holding pointers to `XYPoint` objects, which I think is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. I'll move the calculation. Thanks for the info about what instance variables I need. I can't comment with any knowlege about the pointer question. I working through Kochan's Objective-C and that's the way he shows it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing that fit my original methodology (whether it's ideal or not I don't know.)

```
-(XYPoint *) upperRight {
XYPoint *result = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

result.x = origin.x + width;
result.y = origin.y + height;
return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, if `XYPoint` are proper Objective-C objects.